# In django, can per-view cache decorator be session dependent? (for A/B testings)

Tags: django, caching

I have a middleware with process_request that decides which view version should be calculated for A/B testing a page:
`request.session[test] = bool(getrandbits(1))` (randomly choose True/False)

I want to be able to cache two versions of the view, dependent on the the request.session[test] session variable.

something like this (which doesn't work):

`@cache_page(60 * 15, key_prefix=request.session[test])
def view(request):
...`

Is it possible to make the cache decorator be session depended?

(p.s. in the real code I'm using a mix of 4 A/B tests on 4 different views, so its actually 16 different caching keys, and 64 versions of views, and not only 2 - and thats the motivation to solve this on the view level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use this decorator as is in this case, but you may write your own, which will wrap this one like:

```py
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs


def my_super_cached_page(func):
    @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        cached = cache_page(60 * 15, key_prefix=request.session['test'])(func)
        return cached(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I didn't test it. Just wrote it to show you the idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Wrote a variation of it

Answer (score 1):

@asdasd, the decorator I used:

```py
def cache_by_session_state(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        cached = cache_page(60 * 60 * 4, key_prefix=session_state_cache_key)(func)
        return cached(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I strongly advise you to use @wraps to preserve wrapped func metadata (at least without "available_attrs" kwarg). It's not necessary, but may came handy, and you never know when it might happen.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to do that and didn't know the answer was there, had a problem with profiling the code (it showed that all functions as "wrapped").